# ClassNotFoundException for java.util.logging handler in Maven tomcat7:run

Tags: maven, tomcat, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin, java.util.logging

I have followed the [BIRT FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Deployment#Q%3a_Can_I_use_Log4j_with_BIRT.3F) in regard to getting BIRT's logging (which seems to be based on `java.util.logging`) redirected to log4j, which is my project's standard.

I've subsequently made a BIRT logger like so:

```
public class BirtLogger extends Handler {
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BirtLogger.class);

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        Level level = record.getLevel();
        String message = record.getMessage();
        if (Level.SEVERE.equals(level)) {
            log.fatal(message);
        }
        else if (Level.INFO.equals(level)) {
            log.info(message);
        }
        else if (Level.WARNING.equals(level)) {
            log.warn(message);
        }
    }
...
```

And my logging.properties looks as follows:

```
#logging configuration for BIRT
handlers=com.totaalsoftware.fieldtracker.report.BirtLogger
```

I am using this configuration in three places:

1. Eclipse --> works just fine
2. Tomcat --> works just fine
3. `org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0` --> not working

The latter gives the following error message upon startup:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.totaalsoftware.fieldtracker.report.BirtLogger
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.totaalsoftware.fieldtracker.report.BirtLogger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:418)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:405)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.initializeGlobalHandlers(LogManager.java:1076)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$1100(LogManager.java:148)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.getHandlers(LogManager.java:1159)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:521)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:543)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:659)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:183)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.info(DirectJDKLog.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log(ApplicationContext.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.log(ApplicationContextFacade.java:298)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I do believe however, that this "missing" class is on the application's classpath. But there may be some classloading specialties for the `tomcat7` Maven plugin that I haven't quite grasped yet...

I googled quite a bit for this, found a bunch of "supposed" solutions that didn't help me at all, and I'm out of ideas at this point. Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you really verify that the logger is on the CP?

Comment: Yes, I can instantiate it from other classes in my application and I verified the correct spelling of its fully-qualified name. Also, this same configuration is working in Eclipse, and more importantly: when deploying the WAR to an actual Tomcat.

Comment: This seemed like a simple-enough question, hence I'm somewhat puzzled that no one has any pointers for me. Any further assistance will be much-appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From the stacktrace, it is trying to load the handler using the standard LogManager.  If you are dealing with any classloader not visible from [system class loader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader%28%29) you'll run into [JDK-6448699 LogManager does not load log handler correctly](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6448699) and [JDK-6878454 LogManager class loading inconsistent with Java EE best practices](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6878454).

To prove your handler is visible from the system class path try the following code:

```
Class.forName("com.totaalsoftware.fieldtracker.report.BirtLogger", true, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

You can set the `sun.misc.URLClassPath.debug` system property to `true` or use the `-verbose:class` on launch to get some more debug information on classloading.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's on the application's classpath. But you're right, it's not on the system classpath, as tested per your suggestion. Do you have any ideas how to *get* it on the system classpath per Maven configuration or programmatically?

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  Check the Maven documentation.  A wrong package/class name would also throw this type of error.  Double check your config file.

Answer (score 0):

should be similar to the following, where the cause is, that the class has to be loaded before the application is completely loaded:

https://developer.jboss.org/message/976425#976425

> Your class needs to be visible to org.apache.log4j module.
> Having it in your ear doesn't help. EAR deployment is isolated for
> itself.
>
> you can either
>
> - modify the org.apache.log4j module to also have your
>   jar as resource (copy it in there)
> - or create new module with your jars and than modify log4j module to
>   have dependency to it.